# How to have Asp.Net Identity and EF Database-First contexts in one transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, transactions, asp.net-identity-2

I'm using Entity Framework Database-First with ASP.NET Identity. In my `web.config` file, I have the following two connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DBConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Catalog.CatalogsModel.csdl|res://*/Catalog.CatalogsModel.ssdl|res://*/Catalog.CatalogsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  <add name="DBAuthConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I need two connection strings, because one of them won't work with EF, and the other won't work with ASP.NET Identity.

Now, I need to create a transaction so I can register a user, and then save some additional data into my EF tables (in one transaction).

Here's what I have tried:

```
var authContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
using (var transaction = authContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(aspNetUser, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var dbContext = new MyDBCatalogEntities())
            {
                dbContext.Database.UseTransaction(transaction.UnderlyingTransaction);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, I get the following error:

> The transaction passed in is not associated with the current
>   connection. Only transactions associated with the current connection
>   may be used.

How do I make sure the two contexts share the same connection, when they can't have the same connection strings?

Comment: Provided these are relatively simple, synchronous operations, have you tried using a TransactionScope?

Comment: @StevePy, I did, and it worked. I was wondering if there is a way I can do it without `TransactionScope`.

Comment: could you provide your solution?

Comment: @anatol Unfortunately, I don’t have access to the source code anymore.